# how to update progress bar in callback?

Tags: plotly-dash

I need to create a heatmap, before plotting heatmap, I need to download a lot of data from database which take time like 5 minutes, I'd like to show a progress bar when downloading data from oracle database to let me know if it is in progress of downloading data from oracle.

I googled a lot and fortunately I found a website where it use dbc.Progress() and how to update the progress bar by connecting to tqdm with a file. But I still not sure how to do it for my own example. I tried and it doesn't work, could anyone help me with that? Thank you so much for your help.

https://towardsdatascience.com/long-callbacks-in-dash-web-apps-72fd8de25937

here is my code

I defined one tab, I include progress bar using dbc.Progress() and graph

```
    progress_bar_heatmap=dbc.Progress(value=25, striped=True, animated=True,
                                          children=['25%'],color='success',
                                          style={'height':'20px'},
                                          id="progress_bar_heatmap")
    loading_timer_progress = dcc.Interval(id='loading_timer_progress',
                                  interval=1000)
    
    heatmap_graph = dcc.Graph(id="heatmap-graph", **graph_kwargs)     
    
    #wrap contour in dcc.loading's chilren so we can see loading signal
    heatmap_loading=dcc.Loading( 
                                    id='loading-heatmap',
                                    type='default',
                                    children=heatmap_graph     # wrap contour in loading's children 
                                    )
                                    
    dcc.Tab(
        [progress_bar_heatmap,loading_timer_progress, heatmap_loading],  
        label=label,
        value='heatmap',
        id='heatmap-tab',
        className="single-tab",
        selected_className="single-tab--selected",
        )
```

in callback, I copied some codes from the above website,

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("heatmap-graph", "figure"),       
        Output("progress_bar_dts_heatmap", "value"),
        
        
    ],
    [
        Input("plot-dts", "n_clicks"),
        Input('loading_timer_progress', 'n_intervals'),
    ],

    prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load
)

def change_plot(n_clicks,n_intervals):

    progress_bar_value=0

    import sys
    
    try:
        with open('progress.txt', 'r') as file:
            str_raw = file.read()
        last_line = list(filter(None, str_raw.split('\n')))[-1]
        percent = float(last_line.split('%')[0])
        
    except:   # no progress file created meansing it is creating
        
        percent = 0
        std_err_backup = sys.stderr
        file_prog = open('progress.txt', 'w')
        sys.stderr = file_prog
        
        df=time_consuming_function()

        result_str = f'Long callback triggered by {btn_name}. Result: {x:.2f}'
        file_prog.close()
        sys.stderr = std_err_backup

    finally:   # must do under all circustances
        
        text = f'{percent:.0f}%'
        
        
        fig=create_fig(df)
```

inside the time_consuming function

```
def time_consuming_function():

   download_data_from_oracle()
   # after that, I added below as website did
    for i in tqdm(range(20)):
        time.sleep(0.5)
  return df
```

it doesn't work above, not sure which one is wrong?

Comment: Hi, Is this the complete code? I cannot see the component with id - 'progress_bar_dts_heatmap' or 'plot-dts' here. Also, what are you returing to your output callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now. Honestly its hard to believe there is not better documentation on how to link a background callback with a progress bar since it seems like a very common thing to do.

Anyways, I figured out how to properly do so by combining the examples in the following two links:

- [Background callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/background-callbacks)
- [dbc Progress bar](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/progress/)

Here is the proof of concept of a simple dummy app with a background callback attached to a time consuming function which updates the progress bar with the current status:

```html
import time
from uuid import uuid4
import diskcache
from dash import Dash, html, DiskcacheManager, CeleryManager, Input, Output, callback
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

launch_uid = uuid4()
cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")


background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(
    cache, cache_by=[lambda: launch_uid], expire=60
)

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
           background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager)

# Simple layout with Start and Cancel buttons as well as a progress bar
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                dbc.Row(children=[
                    dbc.Col(),
                    dbc.Col(
                        children=[
                            html.P(id="paragraph_id", children=["Button not clicked"]),
                            # Progress component sets up the loading bar
                            dbc.Progress(id="progress-component", striped=True, value=5)
                        ]
                    ),
                    dbc.Col()
                ]
                ),
                dbc.Row(
                    children=[
                        dbc.Col(),
                        dbc.Col(
                            children=[
                                # Button kicks off the background callback
                                html.Button(id="button_id", children="Run Job!"),
                                # Button cancels the background callback
                                html.Button(id="cancel_button_id", children="Cancel Running Job!"),
                            ]
                        ),
                        dbc.Col(),
                    ]
                )
            ]
        ),
    ]
)


def calculate_percent_progress(iteration, total):
    percent = int((iteration / total) * 100)
    f_percent = f"{int(percent)} %"
    return percent, f_percent


def slow_process(set_progress):
    """
    This would be the slow function, need to set the progress on each iteration to update the progress
    bar.

    The 'set_progress' is a special argument with a function handle to update the app on current progress
    see: https://dash.plotly.com/background-callbacks

    :param set_progress:
    :return:
    """
    total = 10
    for i in range(total):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        percent, f_percent = calculate_percent_progress(iteration=i+1, total=total)
        set_progress([int(percent), f"{int(percent)} %"])


@callback(
    Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("cancel_button_id", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("paragraph_id", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        )
    ],
    cancel=[Input("cancel_button_id", "n_clicks")],
    progress=[
        Output("progress-component", "value"),
        Output("progress-component", "label")
    ],
    interval=1000,
    background=True
)
def callback(set_progress, n_clicks):

    slow_process(set_progress)

    return [f"Clicked {n_clicks} times"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much robalu, I apprecite your help. It works but I still need to understand how it works.

Comment: Hi robalu, can you help me with another question? If I use Jupyter Dash, all the functions must be included inside callback function, otherwise there is an error saying the function slow_process() is not defined. do you know how to solve it if I just define all the functions outside callback function? Thanks