# How to implement a progress bar on Dash app based on callback steps progress?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the following Dash app and I want to implement a progress bar that will appear when the button is clicked and will change its value after every step. When in step 1 it will show 25%, when in 2 50%, etc.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import time

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Run Process', id='run-button'),
    html.Div(id='output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    Input('run-button', 'n_clicks')
)
def run_process(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        return html.Div()
    
    for i in range(4):
        # Simulating a process step
        time.sleep(1)
        step_text = f"Step {i+1} completed."
        print(step_text)
        result = 'This is the result'
    
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8055)
```

I have tried to use long_callbacks, global variables and dcc.Store with no success.

Comment: Have you check the ["Example 5: Progress Bar Chart Graph" of the Long Callback documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/long-callbacks) ?

Answer (score 0):

Updated my response to a similar questions a little to fit your need, you can find the original response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491197/how-to-update-progress-bar-in-callback).

You will need to use background callbacks for this. See below for an updated version of your code which should work:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import time
from uuid import uuid4
import diskcache
from dash import Dash, html, DiskcacheManager, Input, Output

launch_uid = uuid4()
cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")

# Background callbacks require a cache manager
background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(
    cache, cache_by=[lambda: launch_uid], expire=60,
)

app = Dash(__name__, background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Run Process', id='run-button'),
    dbc.Row(children=[
        dbc.Col(
            children=[
                # Component sets up the string with % progress
                html.P("0%", id="progress-component")
            ]
        ),
    ]
    ),
    html.Div(id='output')
])


def calculate_percent_progress(iteration, total):
    percent = int((iteration / total) * 100)
    f_percent = f"{int(percent)} %"
    return f_percent


@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    Input('run-button', 'n_clicks'),
    background=True,
    progress=[
        Output("progress-component", "children"),
    ],
)
def run_process(set_progress, n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        return html.Div()

    total = 4
    result = ""
    for i in range(total):
        # Simulating a process step
        time.sleep(1)
        step_text = f"Step {i + 1} completed."
        print(step_text)
        result = 'This is the result'

        # Update progress using set_progress
        f_percent = calculate_percent_progress(iteration=i+1, total=total)
        set_progress([f_percent])

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8055)
```